# Sed command in python

Tags: python

My input is as

```
Type combinational  function (A B)
```

Want output to be

```
Type combinational 
function (A B)
```

I used code and its working

```
sed 's/\([^ ]* [^ ]*\) \(function.*\)/\1\n\2/' Input_file
```

When I use this code inside python script using `os.system` and `subprocess` its giving me error.
How can I execute this `sed` inside python script. Or how can I write python code for above `sed code`.
Python code used

```
cmd='''
sed 's/\([^ ]* [^ ]*\) \(function.*\)/\1\n\2/' Input_file
'''
subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

Error is

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Try `r` before the opening `'''`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\n` in the string is being substituted by Python into a literal newline. As suggested by @bereal in a comment, you can avoid that by using `r'''...'''` instead of `'''...'''` around the script; but a much better solution is to avoid doing in `sed` what Python already does very well all by itself.

```py
with open('Input_file') as inputfile:
   lines = inputfile.read()
lines = lines.replace(' function', '\nfunction')
```

This is slightly less strict than your current `sed` script, in that it doesn't require exactly two space-separated tokens before the `function` marker. If you want to be strict, try `re.sub()` instead.

```py
import re
# ...
lines = re.sub(r'^(\S+\s+\S+)\s+(function)', r'\1\n\2', lines, re.M)
```

(Tangentially, you also want to avoid the unnecessary `shell=True`; perhaps see [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess))

Answer (score 0):

Although the solutions 1 and 2 are the shortest valid way to get your code running (on Unix), i'd like to add some remarks:

a. `os.system()` has some issues related to it, and should be replaced by `subprocess.call("your command line", shell=False)`. Regardless of using `os.system` or `subprocess.call`, `shell=True` implies a security risk.

b. Since `sed` (and `awk`) are tools that rely heavily on regular expressions it is recommended, when building python for maintainability, to use native python code. In this case use the re, regular expression module, which has a regexp optimized implementation.

Comment: Erm, isn't this just a restatement of points I already made in my answer?